# What is the equivalent of C++ Template Inheritance in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, design-patterns

I understand this is not possible in C#, because Generics are not Templates and they are implented differently(processing on runtime rather than during compile):

```
public class Foo<T> : T
{

}
```

The question though remains. Is there an equivalent or perhaps an alternative way to achieve this?

In my case I have three different parent classes I want to inherit from, let's call them A, B, C:

```
public class A {}

public class B {}

public class C {}
```

Then I have the Foo class, and then MANY more inheriting from Foo but each of them needing only one of the A, B, C:

```
public class X : Foo<A> {} 

public class Y : Foo<B> {}

public class Z : Foo<C> {}
```

So class X needs all the functionality in Foo and all the functionality in A, Y from Foo and B and so on...

How do I do this in C#?

Comment: Well no comments on the answers? I thought it was an interesting topic

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you cannot modify the A, B and C classes (otherwise you could just inherit all of them from Foo), therefore this is my idea:
I would define "Foo" as an interface (that I would call "IFoo"):

```
public interface IFoo {}
```

and implement all its methods as Extension methods:

```
public static class IFooExtension
{
    public static void Method1(this IFoo f) {
        // do whatever here;
    } 
}
```

then I'd declare the further classe as follow:

```
public class X : A, IFoo {}
public class Y : B, IFoo {}
public class Z : C, IFoo {}
```

The only issue (if it is an issue) is that you can implement whatever method you want, but no properties.

Answer (score 0):

If `class X: Foo<A> { }` needs all the functionality of `Foo` and `A`, then simply expose `A` as property and you will have it:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : new()
{
    public T Bar { get; } = new T();
    public void FooMethod() => Console.WriteLine("Foo method");
}

public class A
{
    public void AMethod() => Console.WriteLine("A method");
}

public class X : Foo<A>
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new X();
        x.FooMethod();
        x.Bar.AMethod(); // access via property
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably this is what he is already doing (otherwise why the generic definition?). It would work anyway, it is jut "not similar to the C++ template inheritance" (the derived class wouldn't look like directly inheriting from several parent classes)